# Entity Framework SaveChanges does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have this piece of code but it does not work, and I do not see where id the problem.

No exception is caught.

I'm working with Entity Framework 4. The `SaveChanges` call does not seem do anything in the database.

```
try
{
    Demande_Rage_Animale editdemande = DemandeRageAnimaleDAO.First(s => s.ID == demandebean.ID);

    //frombeanTodemande(demandebean, editdemande);
    editdemande.num_rapport = "111111";

    //editdemande.EntityState.
    DemandeRageAnimaleDAO.SaveChanges();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Logger.Error("==> Modifier_demande_RageAnimale : " + ex.InnerException);
}
```

Comment: What is the `InnerException` message?

Comment: Could you also post the implementation of `DemandeRageAnimaleDAO`?

Comment: Can you provide the exception message ?

Answer (score 7):

You must mark the entity as modified before calling SaveChanges:

```
DemandeRageAnimaleDAO.Entry(editdemande).State = EntityState.Modified;
DemandeRageAnimaleDAO.SaveChanges();
```

In older versions of Entity Framework you can use this:

```
DemandeRageAnimaleDAO.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(editdemande, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
```

It's possible that the method shown in the question is not the full picture and perhaps the entity has become detached. In this case you can attach it back to the context, mark it as modified and call SaveChanges:

```
var editdemande = DemandeRageAnimaleDAO.First(s => s.ID == demandebean.ID);

// whatever happens here?

DemandeRageAnimaleDAO.Demande_Rage_Animale.Attach(editdemande);
editdemande.num_rapport = "111111";
DemandeRageAnimaleDAO.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(editdemande, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
DemandeRageAnimaleDAO.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Without an exception thrown this seems like the correct answer.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'IGenericDAO<Demande_Rage_Animale>' does not contain a definition for 'Entry' and no extension method 'Entry' accepting a first argument of type 'IGenericDAO<Demande_Rage_Animale>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Is the method shown in the question the full thing or have you missed parts out? The code given in both answers should work fine. What is the type of object `DemandeRageAnimaleDAO`? I'd assumed it was your database context generated by Entity Framework.

Answer (score 1):

> The object context must know the state of an object to save changes back to the data source.ObjectStateEntry objects store EntityState information. The SaveChanges methods of the ObjectContext process entities that are attached to the context and update the data source depending on the EntityState of each object. For more information, see Creating, Adding, Modifying, and Deleting Objects.

In your case using EF 4.0 you need call this

```
_yourContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(editdemande, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
```

with version 4.1 its done like

```
_yourContext.Entry(editdemande).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
```

Comment: this code seems to be working , but still nothing changed

Comment: What if you call `ChangeObjectState()` and use `Attach(editdemande)`? Here you have doc https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592676(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: it gives this : {"The object cannot be attached because it is already in the object context. An object can only be reattached when it is in an unchanged state. "}

Comment: how can i see the sql generaed ?

Comment: You can use `yourContext.Database.Log = Console.Write;`

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'SIPSEntities' does not contain a definition for 'Database' and no extension method 'Database' accepting a first argument of type 'SIPSEntities' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) ma.onssa.sips.dao

Comment: Its probably working since EF 6.0. Why you cant use newest EF?

Comment: the project is nearly achieved , and I'm not responsible of the choice of technologies :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131341/discussion-between-m-wisnicki-and-fatidev).